# Positioning subviews of a UITableViewController's view

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uitableview

I'm adding a `UIView` subclass to a `UITableViewController` subclass like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:myUIView];
```

The dimensions of myUIView are width = 320 and height = 100.  Assume I'm doing everything in portrait mode. When I set the frame of myUIView to `CGRectMake(0, 480 - 100, 320, 100)` the bottom of myUIView is cut off.  **How can I set the frame of myUIView such that it's not cut off?**

**Update**:  The height of the cut-off portion is equal to the height of the status bar + the height of the navigation bar.  I think the `UIView` is being added to a `UIScrollView` (the `UITableViewController`'s view which is a `UITableView` which inherits `UIScrollView`) that's scrolled down (a distance equal to the cut-off portion of the UIView).

Comment: Is it the bottom 20 pixels i.e. the height of the status bar?

Comment: It's more than 20 pixels.  I believe it has to with `self.view` being a `UITableView` which inherits `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a status/navigotion/tab bar? if so their height would need to be subtracted from the 480 px screen height. You could also make things easier for yourself by doing something like this

```
CGFloat height = 100;
myUIView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - height, self.view.frame.size.width, height)
```

Comment: Perhaps you will have to adjust the size of your table view, too. Otherwise some rows might just be covered by your view and you have now way to access them.

Comment: It's ok for some rows in the table to be covered temporarily. The UIView is animated in then out shortly after.